# How to not trigger video ended event when it has EventListener

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a webpage with three small html5 videos. When this part of the page loads the first video plays, then when it ends the second video plays, and when the second ends then the third plays. I did this with addEventListener for 'ended'. My code looks like this:

```js
//first video
var player1=document.getElementById('firstVideo');
player1.addEventListener('ended',vidHandlerLow,false);
//second video
var player2=document.getElementById('secondVideo');
player2.addEventListener('ended',vidHandlerMedium,false);
//third video
var player3=document.getElementById('thirdVideo');
player3.addEventListener('ended',vidHandlerHigh,false);

player1.play();

function vidHandlerLow() {
  player1.pause();
  player2.play();
}
 function vidHandlerMedium() {
  player2.pause();
  player3.play();
}
 function vidHandlerHigh() {
  player3.pause();
}
```

The issue I'm having is that i'm trying to play a single video on hover without triggering the ended event which will play the rest. I have tried:

```
onmouseover="this.removeEventListener('ended'); this.play();"
```

But the ended event is still triggered. If I hover over video1 then video1 will play then two and three when only the hovered video should play. Any suggestions how to play a single video without my video ended events from running?

Comment: Would probably be cleaner to keep some state object somewhere that you'd check from a single event handler. You could e.g include in this object which video is currently being played, from what action and then react based on this object. But If you really want to go the removeEventListener way *(which might sound easier from outside but trust me it's not)*, then you need to keep a reference to the function you passed in addEventListener so you can pass it as the second argument of removeEventListener(type, handler).

Answer (score 1):

Since I only need the videos to autoplay once I was able to remove the event listeners in the functions I call on 'ended' like this:

```js
function vidHandlerLow() {
  player1.pause();
  player1.removeEventListener('ended', vidHandlerLow);
  player2.play();
}
```